# To Compute difference of average of one quantity in one table from the quantity of the other table

Tags: sql, database

i have two tables

```
Table1                          &       Table2
Prod | Reg | O.D | Qty               Prod | Reg | F.d | qty
p1   | wwq | 4/1 | 10                p1   | wwq | 7/1 | 45
p1   | wwq | 5/1 | 20                p2   | ewq | 8/1 | 32
p1   | wwq | 6/1 | 30
p2   | ewq | 3/1 | 22
```

i want to take the difference of Qty of next from the  AVERAGE QTY OF LAST TWO RECORDS (ORDERED BY O.D)  and display the difference.

for eg. in table1 for prod p1 average of last two quantities ordered by O.D is (30 +20)/2 = 25 .  and qty for same p1 in next is 45.
So, i want the difference as the answer . which is 45-25=20.

im new to sql and i wrote the following

```
SELECT (select avg(qty) from table1 where   order by OD limit 2 ) - table2.qty
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.prod=table2.prod and table1.reg=table2.reg
ORDER BY table1.OD;
```

prod and reg are super keys.

any help will be appreciated.
p.s- Sorry for the (no)formatting.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide desired results in a tabular format.  Also, fix your description.  It has things like "in Prev table".  What is "Prev"?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that you want one row per row in table 2, with the average in the first table being based on the date comparisons between the two tables.  In that case, use a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.*,
       (t2.qty -
         (select avg(t1.qty)
          from (select t1.*
                from table1 t1
                where t1.prod = t2.prod and
                      t1.reg = t2.reg and
                      t1.od <= f2.fd
                order by t1.od desc
                limit 2
               ) t1
         )
      ) as diff
from table2 t2;
```

Comment: No, I dont want the difference of quantities based on dates. i wanted it based on the prod and reg.   Consider dates in table1 as past dates and in table2 as future dates. Dates do not matter.

Comment: @user3580779 . . . That is what this does.  You only want the two most recent values, though.